# Jetty takes 100% CPU when uploading multipart file and connection breaks

Tags: java, spring, jetty, embedded-jetty

Jetty takes 100% CPU when uploading multipart file and connection breaks

We are currently uploading a file using an embedded Jetty Server + Spring MVC.
When I upload manually a file using curl and break it on purpose with Ctrl^C, CPU gets to 100% on server and only rebooting the application will get this problem done.

> curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "param1=bla" -F "file=@a_file" http://myserver/bla/submit

I have checked other posts where this issue is addresed, but generally it gets solved by updating Jetty API version and Java 8. I have done that, but the same issue is happening. Could be related to spring?

APIs:

- Jetty: 9.3.6.v20151106
- JRE: 1.8_65 (I'm not using JDK to run the application)
- Spring MVC: 3.2.15

Here's a code snippet of the method:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = MY_PATH,
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    void submitFile(
            @NotNull @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
            @NotNull @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            //No code gets executed
            }
```

I have used Java Visual VM to monitor and find the Thread dump for the one which is causing the issue:

```
"qtp529864074-68" - Thread t@68
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    - locked <6ddac168> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ByteArrayISO8859Writer.writeTo(ByteArrayISO8859Writer.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the threaddump you'll see a `.flush()` call from a `Response.sendError()` call.  This could mean that your POST has failed (for whatever reason) and an error response is attempting to be sent, but either hasn't finished yet, or the client hasn't finished reading the error yet.
It could even be a result of a sendError loop (where an error page is looked up, used/dispatched to, and that error page itself has an error which causes another sendError to trigger)

As for the Multipart aspect of this, there seems to be a problem with your SpringMVC setup, as there's no problem within Jetty for handling Multipart uploaded content.

> An example project for this answer was created on Github for this question.
>
> See https://github.com/jetty-project/multipartconfig-example

An example of doing this in Jetty with the Servlet API.

```java
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp/upload", 
                 fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*50)
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/upload"}, name="upload")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        int i=0;
        for(Part part: req.getParts())
        {
            out.printf("Got part: name=%s, size=%d%n",part.getName(), part.getSize());
            part.write(String.format("part-%02d.dat",i++));
        }
    }
}
```

If we run this in a war file deployed in the Jetty distribution then test it with Curl you'll see the following ...

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  -F "param1=bla" -F "file=@big.tar.gz" \
  http://localhost:8080/upload
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 65
Server: Jetty(9.3.6.v20151106)

Got part: name=file, size=23597555
Got part: name=param1, size=3

$ ls -la /tmp/upload/
total 23052
drwxrwxr-x.  2 joakim joakim       80 Jan 26 14:19 .
drwxrwxrwt. 20 root   root        500 Jan 26 14:19 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 joakim joakim 23597555 Jan 26 14:19 part-00.dat
-rw-rw-r--.  1 joakim joakim        3 Jan 26 14:19 part-01.dat

$ sha1sum /tmp/upload/part-00.dat big.tar.gz 
13be13872d0203bae2f8a83ad457f8a0d259a2db  /tmp/upload/part-00.dat
13be13872d0203bae2f8a83ad457f8a0d259a2db  big.tar.gz

$ file /tmp/upload/part-01.dat 
/tmp/upload/part-01.dat: ASCII text, with no line terminators

$ cat /tmp/upload/part-01.dat 
bla
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. We debugged Jetty servlets and found that under a determined scenario, when a EofException happens, a response is still sent to the endpoint, generating that the socket gets on an idle write and CPU at 100%. Changing the source code to abort the HttpChannel solved the issue. A new developer thread has been opened in Jetty in order to determine if it is a bug or not.

Comment: Got a bug number handy?

Comment: Been trying a few different ways to replicate this using Jetty with the servlet api (just to confirm/deny that the bug is in Jetty).  So far, having the client terminate early does not produce the bug (the Ctrl+C from curl approach), nor does having the Servlet toss a Throwable half way through reading the request body content.  Do you have a repeatable test case you can share?

Comment: Yes, there are details on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486826. I will create a repeatable case to attach it. So far we were able to reproduce it on our system and debug it there, but a simple case would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hello everyone. We finally found this is not a Jetty bug. We had a JNI process sending endless SIGPIPE signals to JVM. Removing this fixed the issue.